# Got a cold, cure it by yourself?

Tags: sentence-construction

When a person got a cold, but he didn't want to have any medicine as he believed that it could be got well after having a rest. In this situation, does this sentence below sound natural? Or how would you express this?

> He wanted to cure it by himself after he got a cold.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, it sounds unnatural to refer to "it" before introducing the word "cold" in your sentence. Secondly, the word "by" is unnecessary. I would phrase the sentence as such:

> He got a cold and wanted to cure it himself.

You might also use the word "insist" to emphasize how your subject didn't want to take other people's advice.

> He got a cold and insisted on curing it himself.

To make it clear that the subject wanted to get better without the use of medicine, you might also say:

> He got a cold and insisted on letting it heal naturally.

Another suggestion from [snailboat](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/230/snailboat)'s comment, which makes it absolutely clear that there was no treatment is involved:

> He got a cold and insisted on letting it run its course.

Comment: I'm not really sure whether [_heal_](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/heal) is the right word here, because it usually refers to the injury such as a cut wound.

Comment: @canoe: Possibly, but I'm struggling to find a better word for it. I sometimes hear people say a cold "goes away", so... "Let it go away naturally?"

Comment: I've always used the phrase *let it run its course*.

Answer (score 2):

To be more natural though, building on Stephan's answer, you might turn it to something like...

> He got a cold, but insisted on recovering naturally.

"curing it (by) himself" can also mean to take medicine of his choice.

Comment: Yes, so @Stephan's answer might not consider this condition. But _get over_ really means another thing, which is getting better after sickness. [See here](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/get-over-sth-sb).

Comment: @canoe We use 'get over' to mean that usually where I am, I guess it lost a bit of its meaning! I changed it to 'recover', which is more to the point.

Comment: @Jerry: Good point! I have expanded my own answer to better address this.