# Difference between "do it yourself" and "do it on your own"

Tags: word-choice, pronouns

What is the right sentence between the following (or the best/most appropriate if they're all correct)

> (1) You will have to do the proofreading **yourself**
>
> (2) You will have to do the proofreading **by yourself**
>
> (3) You will have to do the proofreading **on your own**

What is the difference between them ? [A similar question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/106732/do-it-themselves-or-do-it-by-themselves) has already been asked, with no answer. [This question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/7335/by-oneself-versus-on-ones-own) also doesn't answer mine, as suggested by the title my main concern is the difference between (1) and (3), not (2) and (3) (which are very close.)

My guess is:

- "to do something yourself" means that the action has to be done by you, and not someone else.
- "to do something by yourself" and "on your own" both mean that you will do the thing *alone*. It's more about who you do the thing *with* rather than who does the thing.

Am I correct ?
(If so, don't forget to answer the first question)

Comment: You have it exactly.

Comment: @StoneyB Nice ! I'd still like to know which one I should use in the example I gave, if possible :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["By oneself" versus "on one's own"](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/7335/by-oneself-versus-on-ones-own)

Comment: It depends on what you mean.

Comment: @FumbleFingers That's interesting, but that's not really what my question is about. The emphasis is on "do something oneself" vs "do something on one's own". (I don't know if I can use "*oneself*" here btw)

Comment: @Teleporting Goat: I say it *is* a duplicate. The range of valid syntax and meanings is just the same whether it's *yourself / on your own* or *oneself, on one's own* (or *myself / on my own, himself / on his own,* etc.).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thank you, I know that what applies to "your" and "yourself" also applies to "one's" and "oneself", that's has nothing to do with my question being a duplicate. I'm asking the difference between A, B and B' and you're linking me a question about B vs B' while my main concern is A vs B' (as said in the title).

Comment: I can only select *one* duplicate, but perhaps others might want to cite [Is “learning yourself” the same as “learning by yourself”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/60369/is-learning-yourself-the-same-as-learning-by-yourself) if you're specifically focused on whether the preposition makes any difference.

Comment: (My mistake - that one's on ELU. But there's [Got a cold, cure it by yourself?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/6749/got-a-cold-cure-it-by-yourself/6751) here on ELL.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You will have to do the proofreading yourself.
>   *you will need to do the proofreading without others to help you.*

which really isn't helpful since the main point of proofreading is having another pair of eyes check.

> You will have to do the proofreading by yourself.
>   You will have to do the proofreading on your own.

depending on context, could have the same meaning as the first sentence, or could mean you need to got to a quiet corner *somewhere* where you are not disturbed to proofread.

> If you're doing *something* yourself, you're usually doing it **by yourself** or **on your own**.